# Symfony access denied exception on dev environment

Tags: php, apache, symfony

My symfony project throws cache write access denied errors seemingly randomly, only in development and testing modes, and when I send multiple requests in a row. Although it doesn't happen in production, it's really annoying in development.

I already checked [this link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html), put `umask(0000)` in the beginning of my `bin/console` and `public/index.php` files, and still the same problem.

Here's a example of a regular output that I get from the project.

[image: Acces is denied exception]

I'm using apache over Wamp64, regular installation. Does anyone have this same problem? Is there a cure for this permissions disease?

Answer (score 0):

Can you locate the file mentionned in the hydra:description field and check what permissions are applied ?
Event though it does seem like a permission issue, have you also tried simply clearing the cache ?